# thing or things?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

> My friend, Hugh, has always been fat, but **things** got so bad recently...

This is found in my textbook.
Why does the writer use the plural form of *thing*? *He's been fat* is just one single thing, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Things are pretty good now*, *things are pretty bad now*, *how are things?*, *things have been pretty difficult for me lately* etc. are colloquial English expressions. I can't tell you exactly why, but it should always be *things* and those "things" don't really refer to anything concrete or specific. *Things* just means the current situation or the current state of affairs in a broader sense. That last statement in your example can be paraphrased like this: *life has gotten pretty bad for him recently*. We're talking about life and its different aspects, whatever those aspects might be, in general. I think, because there are usually many different aspects to life, that's probably why *things* is plural.

Dialogue example:

> — Hey, John. How's it going? I heard you were sick.
>   — Yeah, but **things are better now**. I'm recovering.

No, we're not talking about "things" that the guy in this dialogue supposedly has. What we're saying here is that life is getting better for him and his health is improving because he's on the road to recovery. *Things* here simply refers to the different unspecified aspects of the current situation (whatever those aspects might be: life, health etc.), but not to anything concrete or specific. So, don't try to overthink it.

Comment: To clarify: the *things* alluded to here are not the fatness, but a bunch of unspecified "things" in general. From the rest of the sentence, we can infer that Hugh has always been fat and this has caused him problems, but the badness referred to is unrelated to (just) the fatness. Compare: "I have always been poor (and it's never been an issue), but *things* (such as the ability to pay bills on time) have gotten so much worse now that I'm also unemployed".

Comment: "Fatness is one thing I'd like to change about myself". "Things haven't been going well [I am now fat, bald, ugly and smelly]"

Answer (score 4):

Check out the definition in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thing?q=things)- in particular the section headed SITUATION. It states that, when we use this word to talk about a situation, we always use the plural **things**. For example:

> We had a few drinks, and then **things** got out of control.

In your sentence, the person is talking about his friend's weight problem as a **situation**, so he or she uses the plural **things**.

The usage of the plural is probably because a situation is generally made up of a number of separate factors, and these factors are the **things** that we refer to.

Answer (score 2):

You can exchange *things* with *events*:

> My friend, Hugh, has always been fat, but **things** got so bad recently...
>
> My friend, Hugh, has always been fat, but **events** got so bad recently...

More than one *thing* or *event* has happened recently. You can change the sentence so that only a single *thing* or *event* has happened:

> My friend, Hugh, has always been fat, but a **thing** happened recently...
>
> My friend, Hugh, has always been fat, but an **event** happened recently...

This changes the meaning from the first pair of sentences and illustrates that *thing* and *event* are interchangeable in these sentences. The *thing* or *event* is not that Hugh is fat, it's what happened while he was fat. This is why we use the plural, not the singular.

Comment: Also, "the situation".

Comment: @RonJohn "the situation" can't be made plural. Try it in the first sentence.

Comment: Yes, but no need to make it plural.  "The situation got bad recently" or "the situation recently got out of hand".

Comment: @RonJohn The OP is asking why _things_ needs to be plural. Using a singular word in its place doesn't help to answer that.

Answer (score 2):

If the point is specifically about Hugh's weight, ike he's just put on another 20 lbs, then it might be clearer to say "...*it* got so bad recently".

"Things" is more about the broader, more abstract situation. Which certainly could be appropriate if Hugh developed health problems or other problems related to his weight.